# Removing part of string after specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good Day

I am trying to remove a part of a string after a specific Character. It almost works when I use the specific Query:

```
LEFT(T1.ItemCode, CHARINDEX('-VASA', T1.ItemCode) - 1) AS 'Item Code
```

The problem I Have is that when I add the -1 at the end I get an error: Invalid length parameter passed on the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. When I remove it returns the Item Code but Adds that last '-' I am also trying to get rid off. This is an example of an item code I am trying to fix: 0C0002AC-GG-VASA = Without the '-1' I get 0C0002AC-GG- want it to return: 0C0002AC-GG

Thanks
`

Comment: why not `REPLACE(T1.ItemCode,'-VASA','')` ?

Comment: That also did the trick. Thanks

Comment: @MikhailTimofeev OP is trying to remove a string after a specific character. Replacing that character will not work within that definition

Comment: @t-clausen.dk thats why it is not the answer, it is a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
LEFT(T1.ItemCode, CHARINDEX('-VASA', T1.ItemCode + '-VASA') - 1) AS 'Item Code'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to few of your item code which may not have the word '-VASA' and you are searching its position and again doing -1 which is negative. so first check weather your word is having '-VASA' in it or not.
like :

```
Case when CHARINDEX('-VASA', T1.ItemCode) >=1 Then LEFT(T1.ItemCode, CHARINDEX('-VASA', T1.ItemCode) - 1) Else T1.ItemCode End AS 'Item Code'
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is if you dont have `-VISA` in the `T1.ItemCode`:
`CHARINDEX('-VASA', T1.ItemCode)` returns 0 and `LEFT(T1.ItemCode, 0 - 1)` gives error, because of negative value.